# tomcat/hibernate takes long time when Database is BIG

Tags: hibernate, tomcat, runtime

I am using hibernate and spring framework, and Tomcat as server. And I am developing my application on Spring Tool Suite. When I use small size of database(few data, eg-: 50MB), It runs normally less than a minute. But when my database size is 500MB, It takes to run 5 or more minutes. I used hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update, so it may take time, I thought first, but when I did off hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=none, I see same scenario. as a try, I have also used hibernate.availableSettings.USE_CLASS_ENHANCER=true, My Hibernate configuration:

```html
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=none
hibernate.generate_statistics=true
hibernate.connection.charSet=UTF-8
hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
hibernate.cache.provider_class=org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider
hibernate.availableSettings.USE_CLASS_ENHANCER=true
```

Please check the screen shot of tomcat server console: 
[image]

Please Help me to solve the issue.

Comment: It looks like Hibernate is scanning your database for tables, etc. Do you need it to do that? Are you able to observe the process during this 5-minute hang? If so, take some thread dumps a few seconds apart to determine what the process is doing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I do not need to scan actually, but I do not know how to stop scanning.